# bigquery : Unrecognized name: age at [1:18]

Tags: google-bigquery

i want to find the age from birth date :

```
select customer_id,customer_name,birthdate,
    date_diff(current_date,birthdate,year) AS age
from database.dim_customer
order by 4 desc
limit 10
```

the output

[image]

the condition is : there's no column age in the first place

Then i want to classify the age for example : <20,20-40,40-60,>60

```
select case when age <=20 then 'Group <=20' 
when age between 21 and 40 then 'Group 21 - 40' 
when age between 41 and 60 then 'Group 41 - 60' 
when age >60 then 'Group >60' end age, gender,
count(distinct customer_id) buyer
from database.dim_customer
group by age,gender
```

but the output is Unrecognized name: age at [1:18]

i realize that the original table is not updated with the new column age hence it's not detected.

how to solve this?

Here's the updated query :

```
#Tulis Query disini
%%bigquery --project sqlhw1-392504

with compute_age AS (
SELECT customer_id, customer_name, birthdate, gender,
DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, birthdate, year) AS age
FROM dibimbing.dim_customer
)

# final query
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN age <= 20 THEN 'Group <=20' 
WHEN age between 21 and 40 THEN 'Group 21 - 40' 
WHEN age between 41 and 60 THEN 'Group 41 - 60' 
WHEN age >60 THEN 'Group >60' 
END AS age_group,
age, 
gender,
COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS buyer
FROM compute_age
GROUP BY age, gender
```

and the ouput is :
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19fj4.png)

which is good. But i be more expect to have rank column, e.g the customer who has most transaction is 31 then it will have rank 1. hope it clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand the question, so I hope the below will help.
Your first query do not update the original table, it's just a `SELECT` statement. If you want to update the table, you'll need to add a `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE` statement in your query.
Thus it's normal that the column age is not recognised in your second query.

If you don't want to update the original table, you could write only one query using the `WITH` statement.
Below is an example:

```
WITH 

# create fake dim_customer table
dim_customer AS (
  SELECT '11555' AS customer_id, 'Alexandria' AS customer_name, CAST('1947-04-08' AS date) AS birthdate, 'F' AS gender
  UNION ALL SELECT '12345', 'Hector', CAST('1990-01-01' AS date), 'M'
  UNION ALL SELECT '76543', 'Maria', CAST('1979-09-11' AS date), 'F'
),

# create fake sale table
sales AS (
  SELECT '11555' AS customer_id, 4 AS nb_sales
  UNION ALL SELECT '12345', 2
  UNION ALL SELECT '12345', 3 # I assume your sale table can have several lines per customer_id
  UNION ALL SELECT '76543', 10
  UNION ALL SELECT '09876', 3 # this line doesn't exist in the dim_customer table, so it won't appear in the output
),

compute_age AS (
  SELECT customer_id, customer_name, birthdate, gender,
    DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, birthdate, year) AS age
  FROM dim_customer
),

# if you have one line per customer in the sale table, then you can skip this subquery, because you don't need to GROUP BY + SUM
total_sales_per_customer AS (
  SELECT customer_id, SUM(nb_sales) AS total_sales
  FROM sales
  GROUP BY customer_id

),

compute_rank AS (
  SELECT customer_id, total_sales, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY total_sales DESC) AS ranking
  FROM total_sales_per_customer
)

# final query
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN age <= 20 THEN 'Group <=20' 
    WHEN age between 21 and 40 THEN 'Group 21 - 40' 
    WHEN age between 41 and 60 THEN 'Group 41 - 60' 
    WHEN age > 60 THEN 'Group >60' 
    END AS age_group,
  age, 
  gender,
  COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS buyer,
  ranking
FROM compute_age

LEFT JOIN compute_rank USING(customer_id)

GROUP BY age, gender, ranking
```

Comment: Hi Juliette, thanks it works but how about to add rank over customer_id from sales table (another table) ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question: could you update your question with the sales table data schema, as well as the expected output?

Comment: Hi Juliette, i have updated the query

Comment: I updated my answer, to add a sale table that is used to compute a rank. Let me know if this is what you need